# Fetch request to Github API in ElectronJS (renderer)

Tags: electron, electron-forge

Hey I have the following setup:
ElectronJS using electron-force with ReactJS and Typescript.
Everything works good so far, but I need to execute a simple fetch request to public github API endpoint.

This is the endpoint: https://api.github.com/repos/nzhul/tic-tac-toe-online/releases/latest?owner=OWNER&repo=REPO

You can try opening it in incognito to see that it is publically accessible.

I am using the following code to do the request (it was recommended in github documentation):
I am trying to execute this request in the React section of the app. The same request works if I execute it in the main.ts.

```js
const getRepoInfo = async () => {
    const octokit = new Octokit();

    const response = await octokit.request("GET /repos/nzhul/tic-tac-toe-online/releases/latest",
        {
            owner: "OWNER",
            repo: "REPO",
            headers: {
                "X-GitHub-Api-Version": "2022-11-28",
            },
        }
    );

    // eslint-disable-next-line no-debugger
    return response;
};
```

I get the following error:

```bash
Refused to connect to 'https://api.github.com/repos/nzhul/tic-tac-toe-online/releases/latest?owner=OWNER&repo=REPO'
    because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data:".
    Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

Before posting this, I've searched for similar problems and found someone that recommended to put this setting in forge.config.ts:

```ts
devContentSecurityPolicy:
        "default-src * self blob: data: gap:; style-src * self 'unsafe-inline' blob: data: gap:; script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' blob: data: gap:; object-src * 'self' blob: data: gap:; img-src * self 'unsafe-inline' blob: data: gap:; connect-src self * 'unsafe-inline' blob: data: gap:; frame-src * self blob: data: gap:;",
```

This changes the error that I receive but I still got this:

```bash
Access to fetch at 'https://api.github.com/repos/nzhul/tic-tac-toe-online/releases/latest?owner=OWNER&repo=REPO' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
    Request header field x-github-api-version is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Basically my question is: How to properly execute an API request to the public github API in the context of ElectronJS (electron-forge) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to fix my issue by not using their API (Octokit), but instead do simple fetch request.

```js
const response = await fetch("https://api.github.com/repos/nzhul/tic-tac-toe-online/releases/latest",
    {
        headers: {
            Authorization: "token {Personal_Access_Token}",
        },
    }
);

const data = await response.json();
console.log(data);
```

Basically I don't need this post anymore, so if someone from the moderators decided, feel free to delete it. Otherwise might consider leaving it, in case someone have the same problem.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to answer your own question and mark it as accepted as it may help someone else in the future.